# Meaning of the set $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I came across a question which requires one to check if there's a bijection from the set $ \mathbb N^\mathbb N$ to another set. I've never seen a set defined this way and was wondering if this was just a typo. Could anyone clarify this for me? If this is correct, then what does the set actually mean? I mean, I can think of elements in $\mathbb R$ or in $\mathbb N$, but how do I think of elements in $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$?

Comment: The set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you elaborate on that for me? How are the elements of such a set, functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements of $A^B$ are function of the form $f\colon B\to A$. That is function whose domain is exactly $B$ and their values are elements from $A$.

If so, $\Bbb{N^N}$ is the set of all functions from $\Bbb N$ to itself. Or the set of infinite sequences of natural numbers (as a sequence is just a function).

---

As a footnote remark, I should add that this set is sometimes denoted by ${}^BA$ instead of $A^B$, especially in contexts were exponentiation is used in set theory.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. May I ask why the elements are functions in the form you mentioned? Are they defined in this manner, or is there a mathematical reason behind it?

Comment: That is the definition. We do it this way because it fits with out intuition about exponentiation of natural numbers. That is, if $M$ has $m$ elements and $N$ has $n$ elements, then $N^M$ has $n^m$ elements.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand it correctly, the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ generates as many elements as the (No. of elements in $\mathbb N$) ^ (No. of elements in $\mathbb N$). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but that is almost trivial, since the definition of the cardinal exponentiation of $|\Bbb{N|^{|N|}}$ is exactly $|\Bbb{N^N}|$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have another question related to the topic. Let's say I'm trying to find a bijection from this set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$, to some other set, say an open interval $(a,b) \in \mathbb R$. What do I need to establish, to say there can exist a bijection? I do understand that I need to prove it's both injective and surjective, but how do you do it with a set of functions as the domain?

Comment: Let's say I'm trying to see if the injective part is true. So, I need to find a function that takes every possible sequence of natural numbers as input, and associates each of them with one real number in the interval $(a,b)$. But what does it mean to have a sequence of natural numbers as the input of a function? And even if that makes sense, what sort of functions can satisfy such a purpose? I hope I make sense.

Comment: @Jobin: If you want to prove the two sets have the same cardinality, finding a bijection is overrated. Find two injections and use the Cantor-Bernstein theorem. Or better yet, if you know that $(a,b)$ and $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ have the same cardinality just show that $\Bbb{N^N}$ and $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ have the same cardinality, that's easier.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11460/discussion-between-jobin-idiculla-and-asaf-karagila)

Comment: Sorry, I can't chat right now, and I won't chat later: I dislike the chat system here.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on / illustrate Asaf's answer, and to provide some context for why this notation makes sense:

Let $A$ be the set of letters in the alphabet $\{a,b,\dots,z\}$. Let $B$ be the set of digits $\{0,\dots,9\}$. Then $A^B$, the *set of functions from $B$ to $A$*, is the set of all ways I could assign a letter to each digit. For example, one element of $A^B$ is the function

$$0\mapsto a$$
$$1\mapsto b$$
$$2\mapsto c$$
$$\vdots$$
$$9\mapsto j$$

Another element of $A^B$ is the function

$$0\mapsto z$$
$$1\mapsto y$$
$$2\mapsto x$$
$$\vdots$$
$$9\mapsto q$$

Yet another is the function

$$0\mapsto m$$
$$1\mapsto m$$
$$2\mapsto m$$
$$\vdots$$
$$9\mapsto m$$

Of course there are a lot of other choices. All my choices had nice patterns that made them easy to write down, but most functions are much more random-seeming in terms of which digit gets which letter. In fact, each function can be constructed by going through the digits and choosing one of the 26 letters for each of them. There are a lot of choices, so the set of functions $A^B$ is big.

Just how big?

Well, what choices have to get made to determine a function? For each of the 10 digits, you have to choose one of the $26$ letters. Thus you choose 10 times among 26 choices. Therefore the total number of functions is $26^{10}$.

Notice that $26^{10}=(\text{size of }A)^{\text{size of B}}$. *This is why the notation $A^B$ is used!* Because that way, we get

$$\text{size of }A^B = (\text{size of }A)^{\text{size of B}}$$

Back to your original question, $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ refers to the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, just as in the above toy example. As Asaf mentioned, this can also be looked at as the set of infinite sequences of natural numbers, since a sequence like $1,1,2,5,14,\dots$ can be seen as a function that takes a position in the sequence to the entry found in that spot:
$$1\mapsto 1$$
$$2\mapsto 1$$
$$3\mapsto 2$$
$$4\mapsto 5$$
$$5\mapsto 14$$
$$\vdots$$

Comment: Thank you for making it very clear for me!

Comment: I have a related question on the topic, which I've written as a comment below Asaf's answer. Could you help me on that as well, please?

Comment: I think you should put up a new question!